# how to change password of an enrypted ubuntu user account?

Tags: password, ecryptfs

I changed my ubuntu user password using:

```
$ sudo passwd
```

now when I reboot and login using the new password, following warning is displayed:

```
Signature not found in user keyring
perhaps try the interactive 'ecrypt-mount-private'
```

Also

```
$ ls command
```

shows only these 2 dir: `Access-your-private-data.desktop` and `README.txt`

I tried to start the graphical interface using:

```
$ startx
```

but recieved the following error:

```
timeout in accessing locking authority file /home/my_username(aman)/.Xauthority
```

I remember my old and new passwords but forgot the passphrase, so retrieved it using:

```
$ ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /home/aman/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

After this I'm not able to make out how to proceed and login to my home foler in graphical interface.

Answer (score 8):

To fix this, simply run:

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

It will prompt you for your old passphrase, then allow you to enter a new one. Then, you will be able to log in normally.

Found on: https://askubuntu.com/a/439290/254032

Comment: `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase` caused me some troubles. See description http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329661/ for your consideration

Comment: On other forums found a hint that you cannot change user password before running `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase`. If you did it, restore old user password and change it only after running the rewrap command.