# Ubuntu 12.04 Keyring broken "signature not found in user keyring perhaps try the

Tags: 12.04, mount, encryption, ecryptfs

So, for some reason i cant suddenly log into my main account, so i did alt+ctrl+f1 and saw the message "signature not found in user keyring perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private'"

I can log into another account such as root without any issue how would i fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me tonight. It happens when you change your user password, but not your encryption passphrase. They are usually in sync.

To fix this, simply run:

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

It will prompt you for your old passphrase, then allow you to enter a new one. Then, you will be able to log in normally.

Comment: For me it worked, but only if the new passphrase was the same as the password I set for the user account.

Comment: `ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase` caused me some troubles. See description http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329661/ for your consideration

Answer (score -1):

Fix:signature not found in user keyring perhaps try the interactive 'ecryptfs-mount-private

sudo dpkg -P ecryptfs-utils