# 20.04 Fresh Install - Log in on GUI doesn't work

Tags: login, gui, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu alongside Pop OS and the installer went along without issues. I rebooted into grub and into Ubuntu. I went to log in, typed in my password, and was redirected back to the start "select account" screen. I went into TTY2 to log in, which worked. When I went to `startx`, the scaling was massive and the UI was slow. [Ubuntu 20.04 - Can’t login after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230434/ubuntu-20-04-can-t-login-after-upgrade) suggested removing one of the desktop configuration files, which I'm too cowardly to do, especially as I have no idea which one to mess with.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: From your description, seems like you were not "redirected". More likely, your desktop *crashed*....which returns you to login. Look for a .crash file in /var/crash that was created around the time of your misdirection. If there is a .crash file, then you know it was really a crash.